# Spacing between text on Frontpage

Tags: spacing

The title on my frontpage looks kind of weird. Because the spacing between the rows. I figured out what causes the problem. It is the use of big letters and letters like g and q which cross the bottom line of the text.

My code looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline, chapterprefix=false]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries iiiiiiiiiiiigiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiigiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiDiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii}\\[0.2cm]
\HRule \\[3.5cm]

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The result in the PDF looks like this

[image]

How can I get an equal spacing between these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a `\par` before closing the group

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline, chapterprefix=false]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{ \huge \bfseries iiiiiiiiiiiigiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiigiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiDiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii}

\bigskip

{ \huge \bfseries iiiiiiiiiiiigiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiigiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiDiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii\par}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

TeX sets the line spacing only when the paragraph is typed and that is triggered by a `\par` primitive, or a blank line. By doing `{\huge ...}` the group is closed before the paragraph is typeset so TeX uses the baseline skip for normal size.

Comment: The spacing now is way to large, is there another option?

Comment: @WalterNazarenus I'd say the spacing is just right but you can use `\fontsize{font size}{baseline size}\selectfont` and adjust the line spacing as you wish, the important thing in anyway that you use `\par` before closing the group.